# Bring the windows of two different apps in mac os to the front?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion, osx-leopard

How do I easily bring to the front of the screen the top windows of two different application in Mac OS X? I prefer to use the keyboard only.

Example Scenario:
Say there are 10 Firefox and 10 TextEdit windows open. Also, say that these windows are having various different sizes so that the windows of each application fully cover the desktop.

Goal:
I want to bring to the front of my screen the top window of Firefox along with the top window of TextEdit, so that I can visually compare some data.

Restrictions:
I cannot use expose (since having 20 windows on the screen already renders expose useless)
And I do not want to use multiple desktop (too complex and time consuming)
I prefer to use a keyboard shortcut. 
Unfortunately cmd+tab brings all windows of each application to the top, covering all windows of the other applications.

Answer (score 3):

Using built-in features on the keyboard only, it's possible, but it does involve Mission Control (aka. Exposé):

1. <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to select the other application.
2. Still holding <kbd>⌘</kbd>, press <kbd>1</kbd> to show the windows of the selected application.
3. Use arrow keys to select the desired window.
4. Press enter.

Otherwise, you'll need to create something for a custom keyboard shortcut using AppleScript. [This article](http://mac.appstorm.net/how-to/applescript/build-a-window-management-app-with-apptivate-and-applescript/) might be what you need.

Comment: Apptivate did it for me. Although I have to press the hotkey twice to bring both apps I want to the front, it's still better than nothing!